# If $|c|>2$ and $z_n=z_{n-1}^2+c$ with $z_0=0$ then $z_n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=z^2+c$. Then define a sequence: $z_0=0$, $z_n=f(z_{n-1})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $|c|>2 \Rightarrow z_n \rightarrow \infty$. I had no clue which theorem I could use in this case in order to show this. I'd be thankful for any advice.

Comment: (Terrible title.) No need for a "theorem" here, just find a lower bound for $|z_n|$ in terms of $|z_{n-1}|$ and iterate.

Comment: Please refer to *"escape criterion"* [**here**](http://www.cis.usouthal.edu/~lynn/dynamics/dynamics/escape_criterion.html).